# net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin with Lombok

Tags: java, maven, gwt, lombok

I am looking into migrating to [net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/), and I use Lombok. So in my projects I had to have following in the plugin configuration:

```
<extraJvmArgs>-javaagent:${org.projectlombok:lombok:jar}=ECJ</extraJvmArgs>
```

How does one achieve that with net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`jvmArgs`](https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#jvmArgs):

```
<jvmArgs>
  <arg>-javaagent:${org.projectlombok:lombok:jar}=ECJ</arg>
</jvmArgs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you add dependency with maven in *-client module:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.12</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You have to edit pom.xml in this way in plugins settings:

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>net.ltgt.gwt.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <configuration>
        <sourceLevel>1.8</sourceLevel>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
        <jvmArgs>
          <arg>-javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.12/lombok-1.18.12.jar=ECJ</arg>
        </jvmArgs>
      </configuration>
 </plugin>
```